# VS 2019 Cannot disable breaking on exception when thrown

Tags: c++, visual-studio, break, intel-mkl, juce

I'm running into the exception:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFDCC6356DC (mkl_core.dll) in AudioPluginHost.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation accessing location 0x0000000000000000.
```

[image]

I am told `No symbol file loaded for mkl_core.dll` which from what I've read should be ignored as mkl doesn't come with debugging symbols and there's no reason to need it.

[image]

So, as is visible in the first picture, I tried deselecting "Break when this exception type is thrown," but the same error keeps happening regardless. I'm not sure how I can ignore this exception as was advised in some [Intel boards](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler/topic/698111).

Some added context: this is a JUCE audio plugin and the alert is associated with Intel MKL. It's breaking on the code, `dftiStatus = DftiFreeDescriptor(&dftiHandle);` and the project is in C++.

Comment: I believe access violations aren't actually "normal" exceptions, so that might be why. furthermore, it's not clear what should happened here: how would it continue? The link you have is talking about something else.

Comment: So is this a case of an error plus Visual Studio mentioning it can't be debugged? In that case I think I know what could be wrong. I'm not sure if I should create a different question or edit this one as the question is significantly different.

Comment: There are actually two opportunities for the debugger to break: the first is when the exception is thrown (shown in your screen shots), the second is after the program has had a chance to handle the exception (to debug an uncaught exception). There is a separate Exceptions preference that can control both opportunities. The NULL pointer deref is not recoverable, though.

Comment: It turned out the error was actually coming from specifying a different size in the descriptor than was the length of the array. It turns out the missing symbols weren't actually triggering the break.